# Project GUIDs in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I know the best way to identify an existing project type is through Project GUIDs in the .csproj file. I am currently using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise and I have an existing project that I can't identify what type of project it is.

The project GUIDs for it is: A78466A4-1D29-45FC-BAC4-B8EAF8D95DD5

The .csproj file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{A78466A4-1D29-45FC-BAC4-B8EAF8D95DD5}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Assignment_2</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Assignment 2</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

- Project GUID is specified 3 rows down in the PropertyGroup Tag

So what type of project is it?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that's a Project **Type** GUID and not a Project **Identity** GUID? Please post your SLN file. What happens if you open that `.csproj` in Visual Studio (what project type does VS indicate it is?)

Comment: VS doesn't tell what kind of project it is. But maybe I am not looking at the right tag. Is there a tag in the .csproj that indicates what project it is?

Comment: @VasantiKasanneni The `<ProjectGuid>` is the unique GUID of that particular project. The Project **type** GUID is in the solution .sln file e.g. `Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = ...`.

Comment: A78466A4-1D29-45FC-BAC4-B8EAF8D95DD5 is a v4 (i.e. random) guid so I doubt it tells us much at all.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, I find that we need to use `ProjectTypeGuid` to identify the type of

project instead of `ProjectGuid`.

I create a wpf project and I open the .csproj file.

[image]

The Project Type Guid of the project in the picture is {60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548}.So it is a WPF project.

Please refer to the following table.

```html
Type ProjectTypeGuid
ASP.NET 5 {8BB2217D-0F2D-49D1-97BC-3654ED321F3B}
ASP.NET MVC 1 {603C0E0B-DB56-11DC-BE95-000D561079B0}
ASP.NET MVC 2 {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}
ASP.NET MVC 3 {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}
ASP.NET MVC 4 {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}
ASP.NET MVC 5 {349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}
C# {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
C++ {8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}
Database {A9ACE9BB-CECE-4E62-9AA4-C7E7C5BD2124}
Database (other project types) {4F174C21-8C12-11D0-8340-0000F80270F8}
Deployment Cab {3EA9E505-35AC-4774-B492-AD1749C4943A}
Deployment Merge Module {06A35CCD-C46D-44D5-987B-CF40FF872267}
Deployment Setup {978C614F-708E-4E1A-B201-565925725DBA}
Deployment Smart Device Cab {AB322303-2255-48EF-A496-5904EB18DA55}
Distributed System {F135691A-BF7E-435D-8960-F99683D2D49C}
Dynamics 2012 AX C# in AOT {BF6F8E12-879D-49E7-ADF0-5503146B24B8}
F# {F2A71F9B-5D33-465A-A702-920D77279786}
J# {E6FDF86B-F3D1-11D4-8576-0002A516ECE8}
Legacy (2003) Smart Device (C#) {20D4826A-C6FA-45DB-90F4-C717570B9F32}
Legacy (2003) Smart Device (VB.NET) {CB4CE8C6-1BDB-4DC7-A4D3-65A1999772F8}
Micro Framework {b69e3092-b931-443c-abe7-7e7b65f2a37f}
Model-View-Controller v2 (MVC 2) {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}
Model-View-Controller v3 (MVC 3) {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}
Model-View-Controller v4 (MVC 4) {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}
Model-View-Controller v5 (MVC 5) {349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}
Mono for Android {EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF}
MonoTouch {6BC8ED88-2882-458C-8E55-DFD12B67127B}
MonoTouch Binding {F5B4F3BC-B597-4E2B-B552-EF5D8A32436F}
Portable Class Library {786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB}
Project Folders {66A26720-8FB5-11D2-AA7E-00C04F688DDE}
SharePoint (C#) {593B0543-81F6-4436-BA1E-4747859CAAE2}
SharePoint (VB.NET) {EC05E597-79D4-47f3-ADA0-324C4F7C7484}
SharePoint Workflow {F8810EC1-6754-47FC-A15F-DFABD2E3FA90}
Silverlight {A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}
Smart Device (C#) {4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884}
Smart Device (VB.NET) {68B1623D-7FB9-47D8-8664-7ECEA3297D4F}
Solution Folder {2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}
Test {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}
Universal Windows Class Library {A5A43C5B-DE2A-4C0C-9213-0A381AF9435A}
VB.NET {F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}
Visual Database Tools {C252FEB5-A946-4202-B1D4-9916A0590387}
Visual Studio 2015 Installer Project Extension {54435603-DBB4-11D2-8724-00A0C9A8B90C}
Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA) {A860303F-1F3F-4691-B57E-529FC101A107}
Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) {BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}
Web Application {349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}
Web Site {E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}
Windows (C#) {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
Windows (VB.NET) {F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}
Windows (Visual C++) {8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}
Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) {3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}
Windows Phone 8/8.1 Blank/Hub/Webview App {76F1466A-8B6D-4E39-A767-685A06062A39}
Windows Phone 8/8.1 App (C#) {C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F111A43}
Windows Phone 8/8.1 App (VB.NET) {DB03555F-0C8B-43BE-9FF9-57896B3C5E56}
Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) {60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548}
Windows Store (Metro) Apps & Components {BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3}
Workflow (C#) {14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079}
Workflow (VB.NET) {D59BE175-2ED0-4C54-BE3D-CDAA9F3214C8}
Workflow Foundation {32F31D43-81CC-4C15-9DE6-3FC5453562B6}
Xamarin.Android {EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF}
Xamarin.iOS {6BC8ED88-2882-458C-8E55-DFD12B67127B}
XNA (Windows) {6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596}
XNA (XBox) {2DF5C3F4-5A5F-47a9-8E94-23B4456F55E2}
XNA (Zune) {D399B71A-8929-442a-A9AC-8BEC78BB2433}
Deployment Merge Module {06A35CCD-C46D-44D5-987B-CF40FF872267}
Workflow (C#) {14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079}
Legacy (2003) Smart Device (C#) {20D4826A-C6FA-45DB-90F4-C717570B9F32}
Solution Folder {2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}
XNA (XBox) {2DF5C3F4-5A5F-47a9-8E94-23B4456F55E2}
Workflow Foundation {32F31D43-81CC-4C15-9DE6-3FC5453562B6}
Web Application (incl. MVC 5) {349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}
Test {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}
Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) {3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}
Deployment Cab {3EA9E505-35AC-4774-B492-AD1749C4943A}
Smart Device (C#) {4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884}
Database (other project types) {4F174C21-8C12-11D0-8340-0000F80270F8}
Visual Studio 2015 Installer Project Extension {54435603-DBB4-11D2-8724-00A0C9A8B90C}
SharePoint (C#) {593B0543-81F6-4436-BA1E-4747859CAAE2}
ASP.NET MVC 1.0 {603C0E0B-DB56-11DC-BE95-000D561079B0}
Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) {60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548}
Smart Device (VB.NET) {68B1623D-7FB9-47D8-8664-7ECEA3297D4F}
Project Folders {66A26720-8FB5-11D2-AA7E-00C04F688DDE}
MonoTouch {6BC8ED88-2882-458C-8E55-DFD12B67127B}
XNA (Windows) {6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596}
Windows Phone 8/8.1 Blank/Hub/Webview App {76F1466A-8B6D-4E39-A767-685A06062A39}
Portable Class Library {786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB}
ASP.NET 5 {8BB2217D-0F2D-49D1-97BC-3654ED321F3B}
C++ {8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}
Deployment Setup {978C614F-708E-4E1A-B201-565925725DBA}
Silverlight {A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}
Universal Windows Class Library {A5A43C5B-DE2A-4C0C-9213-0A381AF9435A}
Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA) {A860303F-1F3F-4691-B57E-529FC101A107}
Database {A9ACE9BB-CECE-4E62-9AA4-C7E7C5BD2124}
Deployment Smart Device Cab {AB322303-2255-48EF-A496-5904EB18DA55}
Micro Frmework {B69E3092-B931-443C-ABE7-7E7B65F2A37F}
Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) {BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}
Windows Store Apps (Metro Apps) {BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3}
C# in Dynamics 2012 AX AOT {BF6F8E12-879D-49E7-ADF0-5503146B24B8}
Windows Phone 8/8.1 App (C#) {C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F111A43}
Visual Database Tools {C252FEB5-A946-4202-B1D4-9916A0590387}
Legacy (2003) Smart Device (VB.NET) {CB4CE8C6-1BDB-4DC7-A4D3-65A1999772F8}
XNA (Zune) {D399B71A-8929-442a-A9AC-8BEC78BB2433}
Workflow (VB.NET) {D59BE175-2ED0-4C54-BE3D-CDAA9F3214C8}
Windows Phone 8/8.1 App (VB.NET) {DB03555F-0C8B-43BE-9FF9-57896B3C5E56}
Web Site {E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}
ASP.NET MVC 4.0 {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}
ASP.NET MVC 3.0 {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}
J# {E6FDF86B-F3D1-11D4-8576-0002A516ECE8}
SharePoint (VB.NET) {EC05E597-79D4-47f3-ADA0-324C4F7C7484}
Xamarin.Android / Mono for Android {EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF}
Distributed System {F135691A-BF7E-435D-8960-F99683D2D49C}
VB.NET {F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}
F# {F2A71F9B-5D33-465A-A702-920D77279786}
MonoTouch Binding {F5B4F3BC-B597-4E2B-B552-EF5D8A32436F}
ASP.NET MVC 2.0 {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}
SharePoint Workflow {F8810EC1-6754-47FC-A15F-DFABD2E3FA90}
C# {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
```

Comment: from where did you get this project guid list from?

Comment: @GiriB, It could be referred from [GitHub](https://github.com/VISTALL/visual-studio-project-type-guids)